# Is a Heroku dyno roughly equivalent to an AppHarbor worker?

Tags: web-applications, heroku, saas, appharbor

I'm trying to compare pricing on Heroku and AppHarbor, but it's tough without knowing exactly what resources a Heroku dyno or an AppHarbor worker will have. I haven't been able to find any official word on what the specs are for either.

Does anyone have enough experience with both platforms to know whether the two are roughly equivalent?

Comment: AppHarbor is for hosting .NET apps, which I don't believe you can even host on heroku... what's the point of comparing them?

Comment: You can host .net apps on heroku (though they will be running on mono).

Comment: @MitchDempsey Yeah I realise it seems like an odd question. We're at the point in a startup where we need to pick a language, and Python and C# are both perfectly valid choices for us. So the client wants to know if there will be a big pricing difference in hosting either language, so I was trying to figure out if, for example, an AppHarbor worker has half the hardware resources of a Heroku worker, so we'd need twice as many, making it much more expensive.

Comment: This is pretty reasonable for me. I do a ton of C# during my day job, and Python on the side because of the deployment costs. I'm really curious to see how the services compare.

Answer (score 0):

They are equivalent ideas though their specs are different. A dyno may have more or less resources then a worker but it will depend on the particular box that it is running, what else is running on the box, if you are using a double dyno or not, and how the workers are containerized.

So they are similar but not necessarily equal.

Know the specifics of their specs does not really help in this case. Unfortunately since their stacks are completely different (windows vs. linux, what ever they use for vitalization vs. lxc) even knowing the exact specs probably would not give you a good idea of which one will give you more bang for you buck. All of that being said they both run on aws (https://appharbor.com/page/how-it-works). I think that the only way you could find out which will do better for you is to run some benchmarks that are relevant to your app.

You may also want to consider other factors then performance (premature optimization is always bad) like which addons ecosystem fits your needs better, which community uses your language more and has more experience with debugging problems related to it and your host, and which one has a support system that you like better.

Comment: You say that their specs are different, can you give any figures or cite any sources? I get that they're not necessarily equal, but I guess the main point of my question is just to figure out if either one is usually more powerful than the other, meaning we would need to pay for fewer of them.